# Is there a way to get the absolute file path of a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to write a piece of code that takes the filepath from my jupyter notebook and changes the current directory to its grandparent folder.

I have found multiple solutions that work to address this issue.

```
1) 
__file__ = os.getcwd()
Main_Folder = path.abspath(path.join(__file__ ,"../.."))
os.chdir(Main_Folder)
```

the issue with this solution is that you cannot run the code multiple times... because it changes the working directory

```
2) 
__file__= os.getcwd()
location = input("Enter In the Path",)
offset = len(location)
Main_Folder = __file__[0:__file__.find(location) + offset]
```

This solution has the same issue as one because its getting the file location from the current directory... :/

```
3)
Main_Folder = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))+"../../..")
```

Solution 3 I figured would have been the correct solution, however, for some reason **file** changes as the directory changes... Im officially fully stumped here and could really use some help from you all!

I am trying to write this code so the line can be run indefinitely, but yield the same result... Which is why I thought referencing **file** would work.

One side note, I am running this from a jupyter notebook which is why I had to do the funky os.path stuff in step 3 rather than just os.path.abspath(**file**)